# Asignar Field Names a array devuelto por GraphQL en React

Tags: java, reactjs, graphql

Acabo de empezar con GraphQL y estoy realizando una consulta bastante sencilla:
Estoy haciendo una consulta a base de datos y sacando "CABECERAS" "FILAS" Y "TOTALES".
Dentro de cada uno de estos apartados, tengo un listado de "VALUES" donde a su vez, dentro de cada "VALUE" tengo un array de datos.

CONSULTA:

```
 name
      cabeceras{
        values
      }
      filas{
        values         
      }
      totales{
        values
      }
    }
```

El resultado es algo así:

```
cabeceras: Array(1)
            0:
              values: Array(3)
                     0: "ZONA"
                     1: "CANTIDAD"
                     2: "TOTAL"
filas: Array(1)
           0:
             values: Array(3)
                     0: "SALA ESPERA"
                     1: "0"
                     2: "0"

totales: Array(1)
           0:
             values: Array(1)
                     0: "6"
```

Mi objetivo es poder asignarle nombres a cada unos de los datos que están dentro de array "VALUES".

Consigo mediante la misma consulta de GraphQL cambiar el nombre "values"
utilizando:

```
filas{
        name: values         
      }
```

Pero no consigo acceder dentro del array "values" para cambiar las posiciones 0, 1 y 2 y asignarles nombre.
Por ejemplo quedado la siguiente estructura, donde obviamente me devuelve error de sintaxis.

```
filas{
        values { name: [0], value: [1], total: [2] }
     
      }
```

No se si directamente desde GraphQL puedo devovler los datos con el nombre o si debería utilizar alguna función de JS para mapearlo, pero me encuentro con la misma situación. Puedo llegar hasta "values" pero no a los datos de dentro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los aliases en GraphQL permiten obtener ciertos campos con nombres distintos, pero no así con los valores. En este caso, values va a ser el resultado de tu query, no es un campo, por lo que no podes hacer eso.

Soluciones tenes varias, una de ellas es implementar un resolver para values, que se encargue de convertir ese array en un objeto con los nombres que vos quieras.

La otra opción, tal como vos comentas, es simplemente hacer esa misma conversión, pero en lugar de hacerlo en el resolver, simplemente hacerlo luego de obtener la data de la query con una función común y corriente de JS:

```
const formatRow = (row) => ({
    name: row[0],
    value: row[1],
    total: row[2],
});
```